# Inkscape: How to resize an image without causing image to shift/change

Tags: inkscape, resize

I'm attempting to make an image on Inkscape bigger and even though I'v grouped the different parts, when I resize it all of the parts shift. I'm new to Inkscape and might be missing something!

[image]

Heres after I make it bigger, the outlines of the lakes shift for some reason
[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't replicate the problem exactly.

However, I suspect it's because there are path effects on the outlines.  Did you draw the lakes with the Freehand tool, with the Spiro Path option selected to smooth any bumps? If so, then that means the path will have a Spiro spline effect added.

If you did that, then before rescaling, select each path that is affected, and click *Path > Object to path*. Do this for each path.  This will turn them into ordinary paths, and will apply the smoothing effects to the paths themselves instead, and it will also remove the path effects.

Now try rescaling it.

Obviously if you didn't create the logo yourself, you may be unaware whether path effects are present.  You can find out by selecting a path, then hit *Path > Path Effects*. If there are any, they will be listed in the Path Effects panel.

If that doesn't fix it, consider sharing the SVG on filedropper(dot)com, post the link in your question, and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: That worked!!! Yes I did draw the logo, so I make everything object to path, then grouped, and I was able to resize without issue! Thanks so so much!!!!